# How to run an entire method with one word?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
player.outputChatBox("Test")
```

Is there anyway I can run the method above with just one word?
For example, `var test = player.outputChatBox("Teste")`

If I type test wherever on the script it runs it.
Also, consider I'll add multiple of those, so the best option might be an object or something (sorry, I'm new).

Answer (score 2):

Make a function that calls it.

```
const test = () => player.outputChatBox("Test");
test();
test();
test();
```

Add parameters if you want.

```
const test = (string = "Test") => player.outputChatBox(string);
test(); // output: 'Test'
test('foo'); // output: 'foo'
test(); // output: 'Test'
```

Comment: its cool and all but why would you wrap a function in a function without adding any functionality? cant you just call the intial function in that case?

Comment: @TheFool its what the OP asked for

Comment: Hello! I tried it and got this error:
C:\RAGEMP\server-files\packages\RPG\commands.js:213: ReferenceError: player is not defined
const test = () => player.outputChatBox("Test");

This is my code:
const test = () => player.outputChatBox("Test");
mp.events.addCommand('Teste', (player) => {
    test();
});

Comment: @TheFool, it's just to make it easier, as I'm going to use the function a lot.

Comment: `const test = player => player.outputChatBox("Test")`?

Comment: Thanks, but now I got this error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'outputChatBox' of undefined
const test = player => player.outputChatBox("Test");

Comment: @Almeidowski Using the code in my answer, if `player` can't be referenced inside the function, it isn't defined outside of the function either. Whatever `player` is meant to be, make sure to define it first.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a helper function:

```
const helper = () => player.outputChatBox("Test")
```

This way you could use it sort-of the way you want:

```
helper();
helper();
helper();
```

Would call the function 3 times

Comment: why wrapping in with a function when u can just copy its value in a variable and use it anywhere

Comment: If the function is pure then, yes, you could just use the return value from it and use that.
But it's not clear if the function player.outputChatBox("test") is pure

Comment: there is no other way to call a function in JS world, other languages may allow it, but not JS